# Conditional column creation (horizontal and vertical conditions)

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

My starting condition is something like the `df` data frame

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(rep(2, 3), rep(4, 2)), year=c(2005:2007, 2005:2006), event=c(1,0,0,0,1))

  id year event
1  2 2005     1
2  2 2006     0
3  2 2007     0
4  4 2005     0
5  4 2006     1
```

I have a series of actors (identified through an id) who happen to experience an event in a certain year.

Here I am trying to build is a series of additional columns that describe a) the distance from events and b) whether such distance is observable.

This is what I would like to obtain.

```
   id year event evm2 evm1 evp1 evp2 ndm2 ndm1 ndp1 ndp2
1  2 2005     1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
2  2 2006     0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
3  2 2007     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
4  4 2005     0    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1
5  4 2006     1    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    1
```

`event` equals 1 when there is an event in a certain year. `evm1` equals 1 when an event is observable in the year before. Similarly, `evp1` is 1 when the event is in the following year - the letters `p` or `m` stand for 'plus' and 'minus' and the numbers represent the distance in years from the event.
For some of these observations the distance is not observable because the available time window is too short. This is the case of `df[1,]` for which we don't know if in the previous years an event took place or not. In such a case, `ndm1` and `ndm2` are coded 1. If we consider the case `df[5,]`, it will be `ndp1` (and `ndp2`) to be coded 1.
`ev` and `nd` variables work exactly in the same way. But the former tells if at a certain distance there is an event or not and the latter reveals whether such a distance is actually observable.

I tried to accomplish this using the following nested for loops, but I didn't succeed.

```
lag<-c(-2, -1, 1, 2)
df2<-df
df2[,4:11]<-0
colnames(df2)<-c("id", "year", "event", "evm2",  "evm1",  "evp1",  "evp2",  "ndm2",  "ndm1",  "ndp1",  "ndp2") 


for (i in length(df2$id)) {

  id<-df2[i,1]
  yr<-df2[i,2]
  sta<-3
  sta2<-7

  for (j in lag){

    sta<-sta+1
    sta2<-sta2+1

    if !is.null(df2[df2$id==id & df2$year==yr+j])==TRUE {

      rw<-which(df2[df2$id==id & df2$year==yr+j])

      if (df2[rw,3]==1) df2[i, sta]==1

    } else {

      df2[i, sta2]==1

    }

  }

}
```

Do you see anything that may be responsible for the errors? I have been going mad for two days trying to make it work and I would be really thankful if you could help.

Comment: You are missing brackets around the `if` condition is the first thing. And you do not need to test for equality with `TRUE`. It should be: `if (!is.null(df2[df2$id==id & df2$year==yr+j]))` However, I am not sure that is the only problem.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that for a given `id`, you always have data for a set of at least two continuous and sorted years? If it is the case, I can show a short and vectorized solution.

Comment: @musically_ut Thanks a lot for your comment. You are perfectly right. The thing that still doesn't work is that which function. Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following my comment, here is what I had in mind as a potential rewrite:

```
lag.it <- function(x, n = 0L) {
  l <- length(x)
  neg.lag <- min(max(0L, -n), l)
  pos.lag <- min(max(0L, +n), l)
  c(rep(NA, +neg.lag),
    head(x, -neg.lag),
    tail(x, -pos.lag),
    rep(NA, +pos.lag))
}

library(plyr)
ddply(df, "id", transform,
      evm2 = lag.it(event, -2),
      evm1 = lag.it(event, -1),
      evp1 = lag.it(event, +1),
      evp2 = lag.it(event, +2))

#   id year event evm2 evm1 evp1 evp2
# 1  2 2005     1   NA   NA    0    0
# 2  2 2006     0   NA    1    0   NA
# 3  2 2007     0    1    0   NA   NA
# 4  4 2005     0   NA   NA    1   NA
# 5  4 2006     1   NA    0   NA   NA
```

Notice how I use `NA`s instead of using two sets of variables. While I'd recommend you keep it this way, you can easily get what you asked for by defining e.g. `ndm2` as `is.na(evm2)` then replace the `NA`s by zeroes.

Comment: I really think this solution is genius. It is so smart that I probably do not understand it completely (in particular I don't understand the definition of neg.lag and pos.lag). Would you mind explaining it to me? To answer your question above, some observations I have are observable over 7 years while others only over a shorter time - a few of them just for 1 year. In any case, I will consider a +/-2 year lag to create the additional variables. Your help has been very much appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the sign (positive or negative) of the lag `n`, you will want to add (a positive number of) `NA` at the start or at the end of your vector. That's why I rely on two variables `neg.lag` and `pos.lag` but by definition, only one of the two will be non-zero. Glad you liked that solution. If it solves your problem, please consider upvoting and accepting it.

Comment: Solution accepted. I had already upvoted. A very small detail is still unclear to me. Why did you write 0L instead of simply writing 0? Thanks again. A great lesson of R coding style.

Comment: I finally tried your procedure but it generates an error. I extended the lag to +/- 7 years and, as soon as it encounters an id with less observations (say, two years), it says "arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 7, 6, 5, 4 , 3". Would you be able to tell why it says so? Can you imagine a solution? Many, many thanks!

Comment: My data frame is very big and the routine isn't finished yet. However, on smaller datasets it seems to be perfectly working. Eventually, I substituted `transform` with `mutate` as suggested by the author of the `plyr` package. Thank you again for your precious support.